# Algorithm for extracting Heart Rate from raw ECG signal

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, signal-processing

Algorithm for extracting Heart Rate from raw ECG signal

I have a raw ECG signal recorded in BDF format (can also make it EDF or txt). Now I have to analyze it off-line and extract heat rate.

**Is there any C# or C++ implementation of such an algorithm? Or pseudocode algorithm at least.**

Reason for doing it from scratch on my own is that late I want to incorporate it into an online analysis system.

I found links to:
Low Pass Filter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter
High Pass Filter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter

... which will probably be needed for filtering the initial data.

Also there is a system created for a hardware module that might be a nice start:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4353/ECG-recording-storing-filtering-and-recognition

Comment: Low pass filter + PLL (phase locked loop).

Comment: This application wasn't intended for medical purposes so you don't have to be so worried.
@Paul: So you are suggesting that after PLL the Heart Rate would be represented as a phase, or when the phase change is detected that would be a marker for the Heart Beat

Comment: @pjercic: no, the PLL *frequency* would be equal to the heart rate.

Comment: This was a real question — it seems myopic to have been marked as "closed".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Pan, Tompkins" algorithm is fairly simple to implement, and yields reasonable results.

As far as I remember the general ideas were something like:

The characteristic ECG shape is called the QRS-complex, where major spike in the ECG (aka the "R-spike") has a distinct shape, which is what most people focus-on. The R-spike is enhanced by a "matched filter" (a filter with an impulse-response resembling the spike). I think afterwards the signal was put through a differentiator. Then then there was a simple 3-point-search after the highest peak. 
I also remember, that the algoritm had a "blanking period" where no R-spike search was performed, since a heart can only beat so fast...

Have a look at this: [ECG QRS Detection (PDF)](http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~severin/ECG_QRS_Detection.pdf)

Comment: This was exactly what I was aiming for.
Thank you very much sir, hats off.

Comment: glad to be of service :-)

Comment: Your link is dead.  There is a pretty good matlab implementation here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector

Comment: Here's an Archive.org link to the PDF in this answer. https://web.archive.org/web/20150319000704/http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~severin/ECG_QRS_Detection.pdf